# Use a "For Each" When Having Multiple Tables

Tags: c#, sql, razor

The problem that I have is that I don't know how to intersperse multiples tables. **For example**: Imagine that I would like to show the user the latest photos on his news feed... I would write:

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("PhotoGallery");
var photos = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Fotos ORDER BY UploadedTime DESC");

<body>
@foreach(var pic in photos){
<div>@pic.Photos</div>
}
</body>
}
```

And it would show every photo to the user... But what if I want to show the user information from three different tables ordered by time (let's say: Photos, Comments & Videos). It would be stupid to write three different "foreach(...)" because that would not intersperse the posts...

Is there a way to send the user information of new posts from different tables to the news feed? I thought of using ajax but I still now know how to order the posts in cronological order

Comment: what is the type of `photos`? What DB library are you using?

Comment: Also, something like this you'd do with SQL instead of in the application-layer.

Comment: that was an example, the point was not the photos, whas the idea of sending data to the user from different tables and ordered cronologicaly

Comment: Combine/aggregate (eg. concat) the "three different [results]" into a *single* enumerable object. How this is done depends, and it could literally be a simple as a Concat and OrderBy of three existing queryable/enumerable source or more involved as a rewrite of the underlying query, but there you go: only *one* enumerable object can be used as a source for foreach/@foreach/ForEach, however it gets there.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: That's why MVC uses model to create your own model and render according to your need